# How do I edit an existing spring bean in resources.groovy

Tags: grails, spring-bean, grails-3.1

I've been having trouble getting grails 3.1.6, and jndi to work with multiple datasources I'm very close but I need to set a 'hibernate.default_schema' on one of the data sources, however it's environment specific.

resources.goovy:

```
    dataSource(JndiObjectFactoryBean) {
        jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/blah"
    }
```

I've read that you can put it in a 'hibernateProperties' on the sessionFactory but I'm not sure how to add the property that I need.

How do I set the 'hibernate.default_schema' on the dataSource?

Edit:
I've tried to set the schema via the application.yml but it doesn't seem to work:

```
someEnv: # rest of the db config setup in resources.groovy
    dataSources:
        dataSource:
            hibernate:
                default_schema: something
```

Comment: There is already a hibernateProperties set on each sessionFactory bean, and the values are set from the `hibernate` block in the configuration, so you should be able to add that under `hibernate_<yourdatasourcename>`

Comment: By setting `environment.development.hibernate.default_schema: blah_schema` I was able to get it to work.  This solution appeared to not affect my other data sources.  If you 'answer' the question I can mark it.

Comment: Cool, glad it's working (and not as involved as digging into the Spring bean definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a `hibernateProperties` set on each `sessionFactory` bean, and the values are set from the `hibernate` block in the configuration, so you should be able to add that under `hibernate_<yourdatasourcename>`.